# Leaflet.js not displaying full screen map with collapsable side-menu (simple-sidebar)

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullscreen, leaflet

I'm having some problems getting leaflet.js #map to go full screen together with simple-sidebar (from startbootstrap).  Any ideas what might be wrong?

Here's the test environment I set up:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwbJzB

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html, body, #map {
    height: 100 % ;
    // height: 500px;  // uncomment this and it will at least display a map.
    width: 100 % ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue in this case are the container divs the map sits within. They are collapsing their height and so the 100% on the map is only 100% of the collapsed height.

I have updated the codepen slightly to show what I mean:

```
#wrapper,
#page-content-wrapper,
.map-container,
.map-container .row,
.map-container .col {
  height: 100%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNyapd